# Is Comma Necessary Here?

Tags: conjunctions, commas

I frequently use the expression *the correlation between A and B*. And I wonder whether commas are necessary in the following sentences.

> The correlation between A and B, and that between C and D are similar.

> The difference between the correlation between A and B, and that between C and D is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

A comma separates a list of more than 2 items. Your examples only have 2 items in each sentence, so can't use a comma.

Visually, the problem with your examples is that without a comma, it is confusing with too many "and"s. I usually try to use "&", so it becomes "the correlation between A & B and that between C & D are similar."

Answer (score 0):

> The correlation between A and B, and that between C and D are similar.

> The difference between the correlation between A and B, and that between C and D is insignificant.

Example 1 does not need comma.  I bracket the 2 phrases for easier reading:

[The correlation between A and B] and [that between C and D] are similar.

Example 2 also does not need comma.  I bracket the phrases similarly:

The difference between [the correlation between A and B] and [that between C and D] is insignificant.